# Module not found, ffmpeg not found

Tags: python, animation, ffmpeg, anaconda

I have being trying to use the ffmpeg module on anaconda for my recent project.
I am unable to import the package for some reason. I have added/installed ffmpeg to my path environment.
I have tried installing the ffmpeg to the anaconda working file, still it shows

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import ffmpeg

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'

How do i proceed with this,

Comment: Ensure if you are using the same environment where you installed ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new environment and install ffmeg?

```
conda create -n my_new_environment -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```